# Grafana - No data when zoomed in

Tags: sql, mariadb, grafana

I use grafana with a mariadb BDD and I have this graph:

[image]

When I zoom on this graph I have a message: `No data points`:

[image]

I configured the graph axes but this made no difference. How can I have data in the graph when I zoom in?

Comment: What's a "bdd"?  What metrics are you viewing?

Comment: bdd is my databases, and metric are sql insert request "INSERT `metric_values` (time, cstep, time_in_seconde) VALUES(''2018-03-15 12:30:00', 'Metric A', 62;")

Comment: How do you tell Grafana what range to display?

Comment: its a graph display